# How to replace variable inside function in unittest- pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a problem with replace variable inside method which i have to test, namely:

```
def find_files(path):
    path_dir = os.listdir(path)
    ...
```

and for needs of test I have to replace `path_dir` from real result of `os.listdir` to some test list i.e. `['whatever1.txt', 'whatever2.txt', 'whatever3.txt']`

How to do it?
BR, Damian

Comment: You may want to look into the `patch` functionality of [`pytest-mock`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) to set return value for your variable.
For example

```
with patch('os.listdir') as mocked_listdir:
    mocked_listdir().return_value = ['.', '..']
    find_files(path)
```

or alternatively you can set a [side effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#side-effect-functions-and-iterables)

```
with patch('os.listdir') as mocked_listdir:
    mocked_listdir().side_effect = some_other_function
    find_files(path)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a kind of eclipse of the mind because i know it, and I used it. Doesn't matter. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: How to mock if I have a list comprehension assigned as variable ?
Eg
```
 def xyx(): 
              x = [s for i in list_example if i >0]   # I want to mock this expression.
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try mock os.listdir to return the mock test data.

Comment: Ok I can mock `os.listdir` but i need to variable `path_dir`.

Comment: If you mock it with the result you need to return, it will return that when it is called so it will be automatically stored to path_dir