# How can you mock a closure (inner function) in python?

Tags: python, mocking, closures

I have a python function with a lot of functionality and several inner functions. I want to mock out the return value of one of those functions. Is it possible to use the mock package to mock out the inner function?

Here's an example

```py
def outer(values):
    a = 1
    def inner():
        return np.mean(values)

    if inner() == 1:
        return None

    return inner()
```

Ok it's a strange example, but what I want is to mock out inner() to return a certain value. I tried to mock with `@mock.patch('outer.inner')` and I tried `@mock.patch.object(outer, 'inner')`, but neither works. Is it possible to mock a closure?

Comment: You can't mock it. It's an _implementation detail_, you shouldn't mock it anyway.

Comment: Did you try to use lambda functions ? Like : `inner = lambda:np.mean(values)`

Comment: Do you mean to change the implementation of outer to use a lambda instead of an inner function? The reality is my inner functions are more complicated than these one-line examples. And also, I don't want to have to change the implementation to write effective tests. It's a fundamental risk to perform a refactor _before_ writing tests, and that's the risk I'm trying to mitigate with this implementation right now (which has literally 0 tests at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've found so far the answer is "you can't". Disappointing, but actionable.

In my case I was able to mock out some other call such that the closure returned what I wanted. In the example above it would be like

```py
def test_outer_mean_1(self):
    with mock.patch('np.mean', return_value=1):
        self.assertIsNone(outer(None))

def test_outer_mean_not_1(self):
    with mock.patch('np.mean', return_value=2):
        self.assertEqual(2, outer(None))
```

If anybody comes up with a better answer, I'd be eager to hear it.

related question [Mocking a local variable of a function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931124/mocking-a-local-variable-of-a-function-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I'm not saying this is the right approach, mocking `np.mean` is much better.**

I have come up with a workaround: the idea is to change the code of the function at run time and execute the new function.

Here is the code:

```
from _pytest._code import Code


def convert_function_in_function(func):
    context = getattr(func, "__globals__", {})

    code = Code.from_function(func)

    source = code.source()

    new_body = ["from unittest import mock", "new_mock = mock.MagicMock()"] + source.lines[0:2] + [
        "    inner=new_mock"] + source.lines[4:]

    compiled = compile("\n".join(new_body), str(code.path), "exec")
    exec(compiled, context)

    return context['outer'], context['new_mock']


def test_outer_mean_specific_value():
    new_outer, mock_inner = convert_function_in_function(outer)
    mock_inner.return_value = 2
    assert 2 == new_outer(5)
```

Explanation: `convert_function_in_function` makes the code to be

```
from unittest import mock
new_mock = mock.MagicMock()
def outer(values):
    a = 1
    inner=new_mock

    if inner() == 1:
        return None

    return inner()
```

Then it returns the new function and the matching mock. You can then change the mock behaviour and call the new function.

Comment: Very interesting approach. The idea of compiling new code for the closure is fascinating. Of course manually importing mock in that code feels ... error prone. But still this is a really cool idea. Perhaps some mock library developer can take inspiration and make a more fully-featured implementation :)

Comment: It's definitely possible :)